# Split by regex with capturing groups in lookahead produces repeating fragments in results

Tags: regex

I was hoping for a one-liner to insert thousands separators into string of digits with decimal separator (example: `78912345.12`). My first attempt was to split the string in places where there is either 3 or 6 digits left until decimal separator:

```
console.log("5789123.45".split(/(?=([0-9]{3}\.|[0-9]{6}\.))/));
```

which gave me the following result (notice how fragments of original string are repeated):

```
[ '5', '789123.', '789', '123.', '123.45' ]
```

I found out that "problem" (please read *problem* here as my obvious misunderstanding) comes from using a group within lookahead expression. This simple expression works "correctly":

```
console.log("abcXdeYfgh".split(/(?=X|Y)/));
```

when executed prints:

```
[ 'abc', 'Xde', 'Yfgh' ]
```

But the moment I surround `X|Y` with parentheses:

```
console.log("abcXdeYfgh".split(/(?=(X|Y))/));
```

the resulting array looks like:

```
[ 'abc', 'X', 'Xde', 'Y', 'Yfgh' ]
```

Moreover, when I change the group to a non-capturing one, everything comes back to "normal":

```
console.log("abcXdeYfgh".split(/(?=(?:X|Y))/));
```

this yields again:

```
[ 'abc', 'Xde', 'Yfgh' ]
```

So, I could do the same trick (changing to non-capturing group) within original expression (and it indeed works), but I was hoping for an explanation of this behavior I cannot understand. I experience identical results when trying to do the same in .NET so it seems like a fundamental thing with how regular expression lookaheads work. This is my question: why lookahead with capturing groups produces those "strange" results?

Comment: Captured texts appear as part of resulting array.

Comment: Please include sample input and output of the desired solution. I am having a difficult time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, these are captured fragments. It seems this behavior is by design, isn't it? *If capturing groups are used in a Regex.Split expression, the capturing groups are included in the resulting string array.* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332139(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It's doing the _bump along_ because it can.

Comment: @erisco, I've provided enough samples. I was not looking for solution but for explanation.

Comment: Fyi - Were you looking for explanation's for split() or how to insert thousands separator's ? Note it's better to separate that distinction since each is a different subject. It's known for a long time to make thousand's  separator is a simple find and replace using this `\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Capturing groups inside a regex pattern inside a regex split method/function make the captured texts appear as separate elements in the resulting array (for most of the major languages).**

Here is [C#/.NET reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

Here is [JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability.

Just a note: the same behavior is observed with

1. [PHP](http://ideone.com/trprJx) (with `preg_split` and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag):

   `print_r(preg_split("/(?<=(X))/","XYZ",-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));`

   `// --> [0] => X, [1] => X, [2] => YZ`
2. [Ruby](http://ideone.com/0NiRT2) (with `string.split`):

   `"XYZ".split(/(?<=(X))/)`  `# => X, X, YZ`

But it is the opposite [in Java](http://ideone.com/5XZTfl), the captured text is not part of the resulting array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("XYZ".split("(?<=(X))"))); // => [X, YZ]
```

And [in Python](http://ideone.com/PXCZcd), with `re` module, `re.split` cannot split on the zero-width assertion, so the string does not get split at all with

```
print(re.split(r"(?<=(X))","XXYZ")) # => ['XXYZ']
```

Comment: Thanks. Shame but it seems I was simply never aware of that. :) And shame on me I blamed lookaheads in the first place before trying simple capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks again for an extensive effort to include information about other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it in Javascript

`number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`

Comment: Thanks. I was aiming at something like this actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, including capture buffers could sometimes produce extra elements
if mixing with lookaheads.

You are on the right track but didn't have a natural anchor.
If you use a string where all the characters are the same type
(in your case digits), and using lookaheads, its not good enough
to do the split incrementally based on a length of common characters.

The engine just bumps along one character at a time, splitting on that
character *and* including the captured ones as elements.
You could handle this by *consuming* the capture in the process,
like `(?=(\d{3}))\1` but that not only splits at the wrong place but
injects an empty element in the array.

The solution is to use the *Natural Anchor*, the DOT, then split at
multiples of 3 up to the dot anchor.

*This forces the engine to seek to the point at which there are multiples

away from the anchor*.

Then your problem is solved, no need for captures and the split is perfect.

Regex:  `(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+\.)`

Formatted:

```
 (?=
      (?: [0-9]{3} )+
      \. 
 )
```

C#:

```
string[] ary = Regex.Split("51234555632454789123.45", @"(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+\.)");
int size = ary.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(" {0} = '{1}' ", i, ary[i]);
```

Output:

```
 0 = '51'
 1 = '234'
 2 = '555'
 3 = '632'
 4 = '454'
 5 = '789'
 6 = '123.45'
```