# Javascript String Split with Regex - Funny Behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Considering the following:

```
var regex1 = /(\[delimiter(:\d*){0,1}\])/g;
var string1 = "first [delimiter] second [delimiter:2] third [delimiter:23423] fourth";
```

I'm trying to extract instances of `[delimiter]` or `[delimiter:239384]` or similar.

Using the following works as expected:

```
var array1 = string1.match(regex1);

// results in: [delimiter],[delimiter:2],[delimiter:23423]
// which is what I expected
```

But string split isn't working as I am expecting:

```
var array2 = string1.split(regex1);

// results in: `first,[delimiter],, second ,[delimiter:2],:2, third ,[delimiter:23423],:23423, fourth`
// I'm trying to get an array: first,second,third,fourth
```

Can someone help point out what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Common issue. Just turn all  capturing groups into non-capturing. Just remove the outer group first of all. Use [`/\[delimiter(?::\d*)?]/`](https://jsfiddle.net/69mLudn8/)

Comment: What are you expecting split to do?

Comment: for splitting try `/\[delimiter.*?\]/`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417891/split-by-regex-with-capturing-groups-in-lookahead-produces-repeating-fragments-i/31418048#31418048